# Java : Selection Sort Logic

Tags: java, selection-sort

I am printing Sorted Array elements using Selection Sort. But I am getting my input array elements as output in same sequence without sorting.

```
public class SelectionSort {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] arr= {1,9,3,0,7};
        int n=arr.length;
        for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
        {
            int minimumIndex = i;
            for(int j=i; j<n; j++)
            {
                if(arr[j]<arr[minimumIndex])
                {
                    minimumIndex=j;
                }
            }
            int temp=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[minimumIndex];
            arr[i]=temp;
        }

        for(int e: arr)
        {
            System.out.print(e+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Expected o/p : 0 1 3 7 9
 Actual o/p:    1 9 3 0 7

Comment: Your code to switch two array items is wrong. Look at that a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

In Your method code, the actual problem is swapping elements,

the Sequence needs to be like this as below,

```
int temp=arr[minimumIndex];  
arr[minimumIndex]=arr[i];
arr[i] =temp;
```

instead of

```
 int temp=arr[i];
 arr[i]=arr[minimumIndex];
 arr[i]=temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues I see.  One is the way you are swapping the items.  You need to replace the item where you found the minimum index.  Also, your J index should start one after your I index.  You can assume that the one before it is the smallest as you are looping through.  I have changed a few pieces of the code and tested it and it works fine for me.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
        {
            int minimumIndex = i;

            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
            {
                if (arr[j] < arr[minimumIndex])
                {
                    minimumIndex = j;
                }
            }

            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[minimumIndex];
            arr[minimumIndex] = temp;
        }
```